# List comprehension with 2 for loops giving too many values to unpack

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am applying 2 list comprehension to do my work

```
actual_skill_list = [process.extractOne(skill, lookup_skill_dict.get(skill.lower()[0], set()), scorer=fuzz.QRatio)for skill in skill_list]
actual_skill_list = [x for x, y in actual_skill_list if y > 80]
```

`process.extractOne` returns 2 value - the match and its score like this `("dkjbdsk", 80)`

I am trying to combine the above 2 list comprehension into one. I tried doing this -

```
actual_skill_list = [x for skill in skill_list for x, y in process.extractOne(
            skill, lookup_skill_dict.get(skill.lower()[0], set()), scorer=fuzz.QRatio)  if y >= 80]
```

Its giving - `Traceback: <class 'ValueError'>: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Do you have to do it that way ? Simple is better than complex. Complex is better than complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing your list parentheses:

```
actual_skill_list = [x for skill in skill_list for x, y in 
[process.extractOne(
            skill, lookup_skill_dict.get(skill.lower()[0], set()), 
scorer=fuzz.QRatio)]  if y >= 80]
```

Comment: The above solution works, but just for clarity is this considered as a list comprehension or something else. I have never seen square brackets inside a list comprehension

Comment: This is still a list comprehension. In your original statements you used `... for x, y in actual_skill_list if ...`. Here `actual_skill_list` is a list of tuples you're iterating over. Without the square brackets in the combined list comprehension you're just iterating over a tuple, containing 2 values.